# Upgrading Android project to use Java8 (compileOptions cannot be applied to groovy.lang.closure)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-7.0-nougat

I have made changes to `build.gradle` to upgrade my project, I am using **Android Studio 2.1 Preview on MacOSX**, this is my Gradle:

> build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Android Studio complains that `'compileOptions cannot be applied to groovy.lang.closure'`

I installed the tools and SDK of Android N, and followed [Google's instruction](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8) exactly 
[image: Correct JDK pointed to]

Edit: it stopped complaining, but Android visual designer gives the following error message:

```
Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later
```

[Install a supported JDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was not solved by applying the above solution. Instead I had to go to the settings within Android Studio and select **"Use gradle wrapper"**:

> In Android Studio select:

File\Settings\Build, Execution, Deployment\Build tools\Gradle

(**Mac Users:** Android Studio\Preferences...\Build, Execution, Deployment\Build tools\Gradle )

Mark: Use default gradle wrapper (default)

This removed all 'cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure') warnings in the build files.

2.Click "File" then select "Invalidate Caches/ Restart.

Comment: @Abhijit let me know which android studio version you have work on

Comment: Android Studio Version 2.1.2